# How do you attach a click event to a jquery object created programmatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, click

I'm writing some jquery to programmatically build a list of links and I'd like to attach a click() event to each link. I'm having trouble getting the click function to fire. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to do this?

This is what I have so far:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="helper/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">                                         
$(document).ready(function() {
    var markup = '<li><a href="#myLink1">some link</a></li>';
    var $newLink = $(markup);
    $newLink.appendTo('.myLinks ul');
    $newLink.show();

    $("ul.myLinks li").click(function() {
        alert('hello');
    });
});
</script> 

</head>

<body>
  <div class="myLinks">
    <ul>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
$('div.myLinks ul')
  .append( '<li><a href="#myLink1">some link</a></li>' )
  .delegate( 'a','click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('hi');
  });​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/zAPgm/).

Of course, the `.append()` would more likely be a bunch of `li`s -- something you can build any number of ways:

```
var $bunchOfLi = $('<li><a href="#myLink1">some link</a></li>')
  .add('<li><a href="#myLink2">another link</a></li>')
  .add('<li><a href="#myLink3">yet another link</a></li>');
```

...and thus:

```
.append( $bunchOfLi )
```

...as in this [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/zAPgm/1/).

Comment: This is more or less exactly what I need going forward. Thanks for the working examples!

Comment: @mksuth, glad to help. Whether this or another, don't forget to accept an answer. Doing so makes it more likely you'll get answers to your questions in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is here:

```
$("ul.myLinks li").click(function() {
    alert('hello');
});
```

That should be `.myLinks ul li` instead, as your `myLinks` class is on a `<div>`, not a `<ul>`.

If that still doesn't work, then Evgeny is right in that you should be attaching click events to your `<a>`s and not their containing `<li>`s.

Comment: Better yet, OP should use `.delegate()` and then only one function will be attached and any/all of the `li`'s in the `ul` will have that event handler.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what BoltClock said, it looks like you're attaching the event handler to the list items, rather than the hyperlinks inside them. Try `$(".myLinks ul li a")`.

I would also test the selector to make sure it's returning what you want. Step through it in Firebug or do something like `alert($(".myLinks ul li a")[0]);`